# Oracle APEX Login issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

I need small help about oracle apex login , after successful installation of APEX 5.1 on oracle 12c windows 64 bit and i'm using google chrome web browser, i entered my login credentials in login page after clicking login button its not proceeding further and even not prompting any error message ,Please help me

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! To help you, the community requires at least certain research from you. What are you search and find about it? For further information, please refer to the help article regarding how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You must go to apex directory and then open SQLPlus as sysdba and then
you need to execute @apxchpwd.sql where you can change your apex admin password. Then go back to apex and log in with new password.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're trying to login into the `INTERNAL` workspace or some other workspace you've created.

If you're trying to login into `INTERNAL` workspace then you might reset the `ADMIN` password with `@apxchpwd.sql`. If it's a normal workspace then you should log in as ADMIN to check the user password.